# parse exception in java

Tags: java, date

I am trying to validate a string whether it is in ISO-8601 date or not, but it is throwing a parse exception, not sure where it is going wrong.

```
try {
    String s = "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z";
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    ft.setLenient(false);
    System.out.println(ft.format(ft.parse(s)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

output is:

```
Unparseable date: "2007-03-01T10:00:00Z"
```

Comment: Have you tried with `HH:mm:ss'Z'")`?

Comment: Your code is still broken, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that `Z` is being interpreted as a time zone so would match `-0800` but not a literal `Z` so you could solve that by quoting: `'Z'`.

[`getErrorOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html#getErrorOffset%28%29) should tell you where the problem is.

Comment: That would work if the input always has a literal `Z` for the timezone, but there are also valid ISO 8601 date strings where the timezone is something else than `Z` - so the validation wouldn't work for all valid ISO 8601 date strings.

Comment: @Jesper, You are correct.  You need to try multiple patterns to see what happens or do some fixup like `replaceLast("Z$", "+0:00")` or rely on the Java7 pattern that you noted.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 7, use the following format string: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"`

Note: `X` is a new code (added in Java 7) that matches ISO 8601 time zone strings; see the API documentation of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because the SDF is very limited ad was not aware of ISO 8601 at the time when it was written.

You can take this code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

public final class JSONDateUtil {

    private static final DateFormat ISO8601_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

    static  {
        ISO8601_FORMAT.setLenient(false);
        ISO8601_FORMAT.setTimeZone(DateUtils.UTC_TIME_ZONE);
    }

    public static String toJSON(Date date) {
        return ISO8601_FORMAT.format(date);
    }

    public static String toJSON(long millis) {
        return ISO8601_FORMAT.format(millis);
    }

    public static Date toJava(String date) {
        try {
            return ISO8601_FORMAT.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Note the timezone, very important.

Comment: +1 for `ISO8601_FORMAT.setTimeZone(DateUtils.UTC_TIME_ZONE);`

Comment: Since Java 7, there's a new code that can be used in date formats for `SimpleDateFormat`, the code `X`, which matches the ISO 8601 time zone.

Comment: -1 since the toJava method will fail both if the string does not contain a milliseconds field and if the time zone differs from 'Z'.

Comment: Unfair downvote, as you can see, this class is intended for JSON interaction. So contract has to be kept in JS.

Comment: @Michael-O: In which case, it does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @Michael-O `was written before ISO8601 existed` – Incorrect, other way around. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) existed years before Java was even a glimmer in James Gosling's eye. The IBM and Sun folks that worked on j.u.Date/Calendar/SimpleDatFormat either did not know about ISO 8601 or did not pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate an arbitrary string, you cannot hardcode the "Z" time zone designator, as the validation would fail for a valid ISO8601 time stamp like e.g. "2007-03-01T13:00:00+01".

If you are using Java 6 or earlier, SimpleDateFormat will not support ISO8601 time zone encoding, so you cannot use it to validate time stamps either. With Java 7 or later, you can use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");`.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

FYI, if you used [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/Calendar classes, you could simply pass that [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string straight into a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor without the bother of a formatter. Joda-Time uses ISO 8601 as its defaults.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z", timeZone );
```

### Validation

To determine if your input string was invalid, catch [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

### java.util.Date

You can even get a java.util.Date back out if need be.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```